# What kind of normality tests that use comparison of moments?

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption, moments

I have these data of normality tests from a paper.

[image]

What kind of normality test that use comparison of these parameters? Is there anyone here who can provide a reference link about this form of normality test?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please post a citation for the paper (not just a link)? This doesn't sound link a hypothesis test, and I would like to read the context.

Comment: Line 2 looks erroneous: the limits ought to be  $0.51$ and $0.36.$  The values on the third line look a little off, too.  Because these tests are antique and the values aren't quite accurate, I would suppose this is an old paper (perhaps pre-1970) and the critical points were computed with a rough numerical approximation.

Comment: Please find the paper here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zqUSkV3M8TvONUf5rZCCzc04eMX-rc_A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @whuber How do you get the values, especially the moments? I've tried for the first line using mean and variance from the previous dataset but they didn't match.

Comment: The easiest way is through simulation.  I generated 100,000 datasets of size 315 using a Normal random number generator and computed the quantiles of the three statistics.  I repeated the process a few times to assess how stable the results are.  There are better (analytical ways) to generate these values, but this took only a couple of minutes and little thinking ;-).

Comment: BTW, this table also errs in (i) not conducting two-tailed tests and (ii) not correcting for multiple testing.  Although statistics (1) and (3) are strongly negatively correlated, statistic (2) is pretty much independent of them.  The problem is that the more statistics you choose to use to detect non-normality, the more likely it is you will find *some* apparent deviation even when it's due only to chance.  Thus, I hope your consideration of this table is purely out of historical interest and not to use it as something to emulate!

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find the handbook related to this statistical test, I will need more general approach to use in my study. Thank you for your suggestion, @whuber. I am only curious to reproduce the values. I have tried to simulate the normal value for the statistics and here is what I got: (1)0.8644, (2)0.0156, and (3)1.8133. I put the coding here : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1x5k_RDEHP7-zzYjU4o_cRMUEcOcMb1wX?usp=sharing. Meanwhile, the three statistics of the dataset in Table 1 that I calculated are far from the written ones in the table above : (1) 0.2795, (2)9.3374, (3)112.7132.

Comment: I just realized that the first statistics is maybe leading to student's t-test, I just distracted by the term "normality test" because I used to term p-value and confidence interval.. I'll learn first.

Comment: These are tests of distribution.  They are unrelated to Student's t test.

Comment: Ah, yes.. The second and third statistics are skewness and kurtosis, but I don't know how to mention the first one.